# int to Long parsing error

Tags: java

```
  class Test{  
    static void testCase_1(long l){System.out.println("Long");}  
    static void testCase_2(Long l){System.out.println("Long");}

    public static void main(String args[]){  
        int a = 30; 

        testCase_1(a);  // Working fine
        testCase_2(a);  // Compilation time error

        //Exception - The method testCase_2(Long) in the type Test is not applicable for the arguments (int)
      }   
    }
```

> testCase - 1 : int - long working fine
>
> testCase - 2 : int to **L**ong throwing an exception

Why testCase_2() method throwing an compilation exception?

Comment: You are parsing primitive type to an Object (Long is a wrapper class and not a premitive type)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you do

```
  testCase_1(a);
```

you are passing an `int` instead of a `long`, [`widening primitive conversion`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2) is happening.

In the second case

```
testCase_2(a);
```

you cannot convert a primitive to an object. Autoboxing/unboxing doesn't work because `Long` is not a wrapper of `int`.

Answer (score 3):

When invoking `testCase_1(a)`, then `a` get automatically converted from `int` to `long`.

The `int` literals are completely compatible with `long` (the vice-versa is not true, however), because the `int` type completely *fits* into the `long` one. That's why the first statement compiles just fine.

When invoking `testCase_2(a)`, however, then you're trying to automatically convert (cast or autobox) the `int` variable to `Long`. Autoboxing doesn't happen here, nor casting is possible and this is why the compiler throws an error.

If you did:

```
testCase_2(Long.valueOf(a));
```

then it would have been all fine.